# {Object} and Object in Node.js API documentation

Tags: node.js

In the Node.js API doc, some items in the list below some headings are like:

[`{Object}`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_console) and some like [`Object`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_require_cache) (without curly brackets).

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a documentation quirk as there's no difference:  in both cases it's identifying the type of the item.